# Vw passat 2010 rear deiver side door locking problem

Tags: electrical, vw, passat

my vw passat rear door handle will not lock when i lock the car. I have hange the door locking mechanism. This has stoped the alarm going off. However i can open the door when the car has been armed. What cam i doo to stop this happening? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!